# Azure Function Custom Input Binding -- Pass both Input from Attribute and HttpRequest to IValueProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am trying to build a custom input binding that takes an array of strings (which are actually scopes) and validate that the scopes in the array are available in the JWT of the `HttpRequest` (as demonstrated below).

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Put))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "put", Route = "route")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log,
        [AuthorizeFunction(new[] { Scopes.Delete })] AuthorizationResult result
    )
```

Currently, I have an `HttpTrigger` with an associated `HttpRequest` that contains the contents of the Authorization Header.  The issue I'm encountering is during the creation of the binding rule in my implementation of the `IExtensionConfigProvider`.

```
public class AuthorizationExtensionProvider : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    public AuthorizationExtensionProvider() { }
    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {
        // Creates a rule that links the attribute to the binding
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        var rule = context.AddBindingRule<AuthorizeFunctionAttribute>();
        rule.BindToInput(BuildInputFromAttribute);
    }

    public Task<string[]> BuildInputFromAttribute(
        AuthorizeFunctionAttribute arg,
        ValueBindingContext context
    )
    {
        return Task.FromResult(arg.Scopes);
    }
}
```

In the example above, I am able to retrieve the input from the Binding, but am unable to pass that input to a `IBindingProvider` where I can simultaneously extract the contents of the `HttpRequest`.

Alternatively, in the code sample below, I am able to create a rule that binds the `Attribute` to an `IBindingProvider` which allows me to pass the context (including the `HttpRequest`) to an `IValueProvider`.

```
public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {
        // Creates a rule that links the attribute to the binding
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        var rule = context.AddBindingRule<AuthorizeFunctionAttribute>();
        rule.Bind(new AuthorizationBindingProvider());
    }
```

All of this of course being a longwinded way of asking how to both retrieve the contents of an input binding's arguments while also providing them to a `IValueProvider`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you check dotnet-isolated ? you could use amiddleware to achieve what you are after: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-jwt-authentication-in-net-isolated-process-azure-functions

Comment: @Thomas yes that was my plan at first, but it turns out the effort to move to isolated is too much for our team at the moment.  Hoping I can find a way to make this work.

Comment: Added an answer, let me know if that help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good article on how to create custom binding for azure function: [Custom Binding for Azure Functions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/custom-binding-azure-functions/)

Here is a solution I've came out with:

- Azure function v4 / dotnet
- Nuget packages: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 4.1.1, Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions 1.1.0, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 6.0.7`

1. So first I have an attribute that will be use to define the authorized scopes:

```chsarp
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.ReturnValue)]
[Binding]
public  sealed class AuthorizeFunctionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AuthorizeFunctionAttribute(string[] scopes)
    {
        Scopes = scopes;
    }

    public string[] Scopes { get; set; }    
}
```

2. The `IValueProvider` implementation will be responsible for checking the attribute scopes in the request:

```chsarp
public class AuthorizeFunctionValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    private readonly AuthorizeFunctionAttribute _attribute;
    private readonly HttpRequest _request;        
    private readonly ILogger _logger;        

    public AuthorizeFunctionValueProvider(AuthorizeFunctionAttribute attribute, HttpRequest request, ILogger logger)
    {
        _attribute = attribute;
        _request = request;            
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task<object> GetValueAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // Here we assume that the token has already been validated
            var tokenHeaderValue = _request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
            var jwtString = tokenHeaderValue.Replace("Bearer ", "");
            var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(jwtString);

            // filter on the type of claims you would like to check
            if(jwtToken.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == "roles" && _attribute.Scopes.Contains(c.Value)))
                return Task.FromResult((object)AuthorizationResult.Success());
            else
                return Task.FromResult((object)AuthorizationResult.Failed());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical(ex, "Error reading authorization header");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public Type Type => typeof(AuthorizationResult);

    public string ToInvokeString() => string.Empty;
}
```

3. The `IBinding` implementation will be responsible for injecting the http request:

```csharp
public class AuthorizeFunctionBinding : IBinding
{
    private readonly AuthorizeFunctionAttribute _attribute;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AuthorizeFunctionBinding(AuthorizeFunctionAttribute attribute, ILogger logger)
    {
        _attribute = attribute;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task<IValueProvider> BindAsync(BindingContext context)
    {
        // Get the HTTP request
        var request = context.BindingData["req"] as HttpRequest;
        return Task.FromResult<IValueProvider>(new AuthorizeFunctionValueProvider(_attribute, request, _logger));
    }

    public bool FromAttribute => true;

    public Task<IValueProvider> BindAsync(object value, ValueBindingContext context)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public ParameterDescriptor ToParameterDescriptor() => new ParameterDescriptor();
}
```

4. The `IBindingProvider` implementation will be responsible for getting the attribute scopes:

```csharp
public class AuthorizeFunctionBindingProvider : IBindingProvider
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AuthorizeFunctionBindingProvider(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task<IBinding> TryCreateAsync(BindingProviderContext context)
    {
        var attr = context.Parameter.GetCustomAttribute<AuthorizeFunctionAttribute>(inherit: false);
        return Task.FromResult((IBinding)new AuthorizeFunctionBinding(attr, _logger));
    }
}
```

5. The `IExtensionConfigProvider` implementation will be responsible for adding a binding rule to the azure function configuration:

```chsarp
public class BindingExtensionProvider : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public BindingExtensionProvider(ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {
        context.AddBindingRule<AuthorizeFunctionAttribute>().Bind(new AuthorizeFunctionBindingProvider(_logger));
    }
}
```

6. The `Startup` class will register the dependencies:

```chsarp
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp2.Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // IWebJobsBuilders instance
            var wbBuilder = builder.Services.AddWebJobs(x => { return; });

            // And now you can use AddExtension
            wbBuilder.AddExtension<BindingExtensionProvider>();
        }
    }
}
```

you can now use the new binding in your function:

```chsarp
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run1(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log,
    [AuthorizeFunction(new[] { "Delete" })] AuthorizationResult result)
{
    ...
}

[FunctionName("Function2")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run2(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log,
    [AuthorizeFunction(new[] { "Create", "update" })] AuthorizationResult result)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yup this works great!  I had no clue that you could access the Attribute in the BindingProviderContext.  Really excited I dont have to throw all this work away, thanks again!!

Comment: Yeah clearly not obvious, I was lucky I found a nice article I aslo look at some of the bindings in the azure webjob repo

Comment: This works however, it is not possible to take advantage of the attribute’s `[AutoResolve]` decorators this way. Which means that we need to fetch values from app settings ourselves. Is there a builtin way to make auto-resolution work?

Answer (score -1):

If calling the AddWebjobs extension method is just to obtain an instance of IWebJobsBuilder then I propose a slightly cleaner solution. Since the only purpose of IWebJobsBuilder is to hold the IServicesCollection instance, then I think that just providing a shim is a cleaner approach. (The AddWebJobs extension method is  horrendous; take a look inside).

```c#
internal class WebJobsBuilderShim : IWebJobsBuilder
{
    public WebJobsBuilderShim(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Services = services;
    }

    public IServiceCollection Services { get; }
}
```

```c#
    public static IWebJobsExtensionBuilder AddExtension<TExtension>(this IServiceCollection services) where TExtension : class, IExtensionConfigProvider
    {
        return new WebJobsBuilderShim(services).AddExtension<TExtension>();
    }
```

Usage:

```
        services.AddExtension<KeyVaultExtensionConfigProvider>().BindOptions<KeyVaultOptions>();
```